# How to simplify or statement

Tags: javascript, performance, logic, comparison

Is there a way to simplify this statement to be a 'prettier' comparison:

```
    a <= 1 ||
    b <= 1 ||
    d <= 1 ||
    !c;
```

Comment: What are `a`, `b` and `c` ? are there any constraints?

Comment: Is it really necessary? Imho it looks "pretty" enough now.

Answer (score 4):

You could put `a`, `b`, and `d` in an array, and check whether `some` of them are `<= 1`:

```
[a, b, d].some(num => num <= 1) || !c
```